# SUMMARIZE (dax) equivalent in Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dax

I am new using Pandas in Python and I am facing an issue that i am not able to solve alone.

I connecting by odbc,SQL, to get df = the following data:

```
             JDFEC JDCPY JDTMP  PALLETS_STOCK
0       2021-06-30   164     N         1256.0
1       2022-01-27   704     N            1.0
2       2021-03-14   799     N          376.0
3       2022-01-14   723     N         1402.0
4       2022-05-19   776     N         1902.0
...            ...   ...   ...            ...
101417  2022-10-12   714     N          220.0
101418  2020-09-14   153     N          315.0
101419  2021-05-08   109     I           66.0
101420  2022-10-14   057     N           48.0
101421  2022-04-27   776     I         1820.0
```

I would like to manipulate it to get an outpute similar to the image:
[New Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4PuV.png)
(So grouping by date and creating groups regarding JDCPY and JDTMP values to sum PALLETS_STOCK)

I already have Power BI doing it with a SUMMARIZE-CALCULATE-SUM as below:

```
NewTable = 
    SUMMARIZE(
    Query,
    Query[JDFEC],

    "GROUP-A",
        CALCULATE(SUM(Query[PALLETS_STOCKS], QueryKeynes[JDCPY] = "539" || QueryKeynes[JDCPY] = "109"),

    "GROUP-B",
        CALCULATE(SUM(Query[PALLETS_STOCKS], QueryKeynes[JDCPY] = "455", QueryKeynes[JDTMP] = "N"),

etc...

)
```

However I have no idea about how I could deal with it in Python ?

Someone could guide me please ?

**EDIT: Final code**

```
    conditions = [
                    df["JDCPY"].isin(["003", '006']),
                    (df["JDCPY"].eq("022")) & (df["JDTMP"].eq("N"))
                ]

    groups= ["GROUP-A","GROUP-B"]

    out= (
            df
            .assign(JDFEC= pd.to_datetime(df["JDFEC"]),
                    GROUPS= np.select(conditions, groups, default="GROUP-X"))
            .groupby(["JDFEC", "GROUPS"], as_index=False)["PALLETS_STOCK"].sum()
            .pivot_table(index= "JDFEC", columns="GROUPS", values="PALLETS_STOCK")
            .reset_index()
            .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        ) 
    

    out.sort_values(by=["JDFEC"])
    out["JDFEC"] = pd.to_datetime(out["JDFEC"]).dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

    
    print (out)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [**`np.select`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to form the groups and [**`pandas.pivot_table`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) to reshape.

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

conditions = [
                df["JDCPY"].isin([539, 109]),
                (df["JDCPY"].eq(455)) & (df["JDTMP"].eq("N"))
             ]

groups= ["GROUP-A","GROUP-B"]

out= (
        df
         .assign(JDFEC= pd.to_datetime(df["JDFEC"]).dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),
                 GROUPS= np.select(conditions, choices, default="GROUP-X"))
         .groupby(["JDFEC", "GROUPS"], as_index=False)["PALLETS_STOCK"].sum()
         .pivot_table(index= "JDFEC", columns="GROUPS", values="PALLETS_STOCK")
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
     )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)
    
        JDFEC  GROUP-A  GROUP-B  GROUP-X
0  08/05/2021     66.0      NaN      NaN
1  12/10/2022    220.0      NaN      NaN
2  14/01/2022      NaN      NaN   1402.0
3  14/09/2020      NaN    315.0      NaN
4  14/10/2022      NaN      NaN     48.0
5  19/05/2022      NaN      NaN   1902.0
6  27/01/2022    377.0      NaN      NaN
7  27/04/2022      NaN      NaN   1820.0
8  30/06/2021      NaN      NaN   1256.0
```

##### # Input used :

```
print(df)

        JDFEC  JDCPY JDTMP  PALLETS_STOCK
0  2021-06-30    164     N         1256.0
1  2022-01-27    109     N            1.0
2  2022-01-27    109     N          376.0
3  2022-01-14    723     N         1402.0
4  2022-05-19    776     N         1902.0
5  2022-10-12    539     N          220.0
6  2020-09-14    455     N          315.0
7  2021-05-08    109     I           66.0
8  2022-10-14     57     N           48.0
9  2022-04-27    776     I         1820.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer however it does not work and it seems your summing JDCPY instead of PALLETS_STOCK

Comment: Easy to fix, see update. But what do you mean by _it does not work_ ?

Comment: Thank you. I have been putting the code I am using in the EDIT part of my post and changing the conditions as text because it is stored this way in the DB. I don´t know what is the problem as the code is going well line by line until .pivot where it touch the above df before jumping to the except

Comment: Can you remove the `try .. except` bloc to see what error throws python ?

Comment: I have been adding the error message in edit 2. If I understand it´s from the .with line ?

Comment: It seems that the error occurs when we try to `.pivot`. I made a small edit, can you check that ?

Comment: With "choices" instead of groups the error message says that it is not defined. If I let groups it's giving me Group-A, B and X accurately. However, i can have different rows of Groups A, B, or X for the same date, which summed together would be the great result. I have tried to modify .groupby but without success. I had the current output in EDIT 3. For example 5216 corresponds to the value of isin 539 and 1363 to the isin 109. Should i need to apply a new groupby on the out ?

Comment: Based on your EDIT 3, I think `pandas.pivot_table` should handle this kind of scenarios. I updated my answer ;)

Comment: Thank you ! I changed it a little bit to be able to sort the date without the US format, and add it in the EDIT of my post. Thank you, I am starting to understand a bit more how is interacting pandas with numpy  !